# Firestore DocumentSnapshot exists issue with Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So, what's the point of having `.exists()`, if the promise always fails because the document is not found ( it doesn't actually exist yet ).

```
match /conversations/{conversationId} {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.participants
}
```

This would be the query ( minimalistic example )

```
store.conversations
    .doc( conversationId )
    .get()
    .then( async snapshot => {
        if ( !snapshot.exists )
            data = await dispatch( startConversation( participant ) )
    }
    .catch( console.err )
```

That dispatch would never trigger if the document does not exist, because the security rules expect `request.auth.uid` to be in the `resource.data.participants` array, which sometimes, is not the case.

The only way I can think of fixing this is to change the security rules to allow reading when the document does not exist. But that simply feels counter-intuitive.

```
match /conversations/{conversationId} {

    function conversationExists(conversationId) {
        return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/conversations/$(conversationId))
    }

    allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.participants || !conversationExists(conversationId)

}
```

I would treat the issue within `.catch()` but, I can't know if it's a document missing issue or some other thing which caused it ( timeout, network issues, whatever ).

Any clue as to what is considered best practice in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is here.  It sounds like you're expecting to know if a document exists, even if security rules say you should not know anything about that document, if it existed?  Or are you just saying you need to be able to distinguish between different [error cases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FirestoreError)?

Comment: Let's say two users want to chat. One creates the room, so I have to do a pre-check in case the room already exists, so I don't create another room with the same participants in it. In order to figure out if that room already exists, I have to get the document with the persistent (unique)  conversationId between the two. Given that conversation doesn't actually exist, I should be returning a snapshot with `exists() == false` correct ? 

Hence, the only solution I thought of, was to allow get access if a user is in the conversation's participants array or if the room doesn't exist at all.

Comment: If the security rule works, then why don't you just run with it?  You've written the logic that expresses the conditions.  I don't think you should feel bad about it.

Comment: Yeah, works fine, I was just wondering what's considered best practice in this scenario.